# closing a java application which communicates with an arduino board

Tags: java, netbeans, bluetooth, serial-port

I need to close an application which actually connects with the arduino board via Bluetooth serial port and displays values from arduino board.

Once my application starts it works well and gives the output as expected. But when i try to close my application it does not close automatically i use task manager to close it.

Suppose if i did not connect with any arduino board then my application closes well. Now i want to close the application when the button is pressed and the communication has to stop.

I used `System.exit(0);
        p.destroy();`
but it does not close my application when it is communicating.

Comment: can anyone answer my question ? pls help me out n dis issue.